# Bochs compilation error on Cygwin

Tags: operating-system, cygwin, bochs, pintos

I am trying to build Bochs on Cygwin in accordance with [this tutorial](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs140/projects/pintos/pintos_12.html#SEC167) at section G.1. When I attempt to enter the command `./configure --enable-gdb-stub` I get the following output:

```
checking build system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking host system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking target system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking if you are configuring for another platform... no
checking for standard CFLAGS on this platform... -mno-cygwin -DWIN32
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

The violating lines of my `config.log` file are:

```
configure:2132: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2135: gcc  -mno-cygwin -DWIN32  -mno-cygwin -DWIN32  conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
configure:2138: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
/* confdefs.h */
...
```

I am new to OS work and this issue has me stuck for hours. I don't understand why `-mno-cygwin` is even being passed as an argument for `gcc`. Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it says

> It has been most extensively tested on GNU/Linux, in particular the Debian and Ubuntu distributions, and Solaris. It is not designed to install under any form of Windows.

Using cygwin in Windows is the problem as I see. Try in Ubuntu Linux.